How to test my Dapp
I'm developing a Dapp "ETHome" in order to put in practice my skills got until now, so  i've wrote some contracts and tested them using hardhat, then i started using ethers.js and react js for the user interface, but i got confused...
If i'm running my contracts locally using hardhat, but i also want to use sepolia in order to execute transactions like "Listing apartments, user registration, etc..." with testnet ETH, is it possible to use both? or what do u recommend me to do? or do i have to deploy my contracts elsewhere?
Here is my github where u can find the application, if u want to contribute go ahead as it is open source and any suggestions to improve my skills are welcome.
Github:  https://github.com/Juriep
Thanks for your time,
All best, Juriep.

I think a local network is good for unit testing like you're doing. Deploying on the testnet is great if you want to share a demo of your app with other people.

Thanks for your answer
